# PATH issue on MAC

Tags: macos, path

I am facing an issue that I couldn't solve (using OSX EL CAPITAN 10.11.6)

I am using the bash terminal (shell). Here is my `/.bash_profile`:

```
source ~/.profile
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/bin/"
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phalcon-devtools:$PATH"
export PTOOLSPATH=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phalcon-devtools
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
```

Everytime i reboot my computer the PATH contains `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"` only and i have to export everything manually.

Moreover when i install something in my `"/usr/local/bin/"` directory it is not taken in account when i reboot. For example I installed **Angular.js** this morning. And after rebooting if i type `"ng -v"` in my bash terminal I get `"command not found"`.

Do you have any idea about what's happening with my computer??
Thank you for your time!

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? What shell is it configured to run when you load it? What options are you loading that shell with?

Comment: "For example i installed Angular.js this morning" — How? Where did the `ng` file get saved? Is it still there?

Comment: On line 2 you replace the whole PATH with a hard coded one. On line 3 you prepend a value to it. On line 5, you prepend some more values to it. On line 6 you **erase everything** that lines 2, 3 and 5 did.

Comment: Thank you for your reactivity Quentin. Indeed the ng file get saved and is still in the directory /usr/local/bin/. For your questions about the shell i'm afraid i can't tell. So do you know how to not erase previous path when exporting one ?

Comment: Ok i get it, i had to do PATH=$PATH: followed by the link. But it doesn't solve the issue. Do you know why everything installed in my /usr/local/bin is not recognized as a command? (npm, ng, composer,....) And why my PATH isn't working ??? If i type php -v i get 5.3.8 although it is 7.2.1 in my PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found out what went wrong. 
If someone is experiencing the same issue you have to set your ./profile (or ./bash_profile) as follow

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```